# perl grep 10 lines of log

Tags: regex, perl

I am interesting to grab 10 lines before it match the regex "critical" or "error"  .
currently I am printing $_ which gives me only the line of the regex match.

I Worte in perl the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
open LOG, "/Users/erangross/Projects/perl/log" or die;

while (<LOG>){
    if (/critical | error/){
        open (myFile, '>>parser_log.txt');
        print myFile $_;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Arrays. They can help. Here I use it as a sort of FIFO or queue:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open LOG, "<", "/Users/erangross/Projects/perl/log" or die "Can't open log: $!";
open my $parseLog, '>>', 'parser_log.txt') or die "Can't open output file: $!";

my @lastTenLines;

while (<LOG>){
    push @lastTenLines, $_; # add current line.
    shift @lastTenLines while @lastTenLines > 10; # remove lines outside your scope.
    print $parseLog @lastTenLines if /critical | error/x; # print if there is a find.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Does it have to be perl? GNU `grep` gives you the option of printing a specified number of lines of 'context' before/after a matching line, e.g

```
grep --before-context=10 '(critical \| error)' parserlog.txt
```

Comment: Same with [ack](http://betterthangrep.com), which *is* Perl: `ack -B 10 'critical | error' /Users/erangross/Projects/perl/log`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Tie::File`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aFile). It has been a core module since Perl v5.7.3 and so shouldn't need installing.

`Tie::File` allows you to randomly access records within a file as if they were array elements. The problem is reduced to simply keeping track of the index of the array that matches, and printing all elements from an index of nine less.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;

open my $plog, '>', 'parser_log.txt' or die $!;
tie my @log, 'Tie::File', '/Users/erangross/Projects/perl/log' or die $!;

for my $i (0 .. $#log) {
  next unless / critical | error /xi;
  my $start = $i > 9 ? $i - 9 : 0;
  print $plog $log[$_] for $start .. $i;
}
```